# Long table six pages

Tags: longtable

I have long table "six pages" in word. I'm moving my work to latex but the table appears in bad way and not showing all the rows nether the columns.

[image]

```
\begin{longtable}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{List of published articles selected for the systematic review}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|l|c|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
    \textbf{ID} &
    \textbf{Reference} &
    \textbf{Year} &
    \textbf{Country} &
    \textbf{Study Period} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Model / Methods}} &
    \textbf{Techniques Category} \\ \hline
1 &
  \cite{hales2002potential} &
  2002 &
  Global &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1975\\ -\\ 1996\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- Logistic Regression\\ - Spatial
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  You don't have to nest a `tabular` environment in a `longtable`. Also, if you want columns with multiline cells, don't use the `r, l` or `c` column types. Last you point, you should read the longtable documentation, as it has a special syntax.

Comment: Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Also, what kind of contents will the "Techniques categories"  column contain: single words, lext, a list,...?

Answer (score 1):

Your table is quite wide and I seriously doubt it will fit onto a page while keeping a reasonable font size and margins. I therefore suggest to rotate the table to landscape orientation. The following may serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{label=--, noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, after=\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|r|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}|c|X|X|}
    \caption{List of published articles selected for the systematic review}
    \label{tab:my-table}\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
    \textbf{ID} &
    \textbf{Ref.} &
    \textbf{Year} &
    \textbf{Country} &
    \textbf{Study Period} &
    \textbf{Model / Methods} &
    \textbf{Techniques Category} \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{List of published articles selected for the systematic review - continued from previous page}\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
    \textbf{ID} &
    \textbf{Ref.} &
    \textbf{Year} &
    \textbf{Country} &
    \textbf{Study Period} &
    \textbf{Model / Methods} &
    \textbf{Techniques Category} \\ \hline
    \endhead
1 &
  \cite{hales2002potential} &
  2002 &
  Global &
 1975 -- 1996 &
 \begin{tabitem}
   \item Logistic Regression
   \item Spatial
 \end{tabitem} &
 some text in the last column 
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited it but the table still contain problems. The text in the columns are over each other

Comment: I have saved my table as PDF (six pages) and used this commands lines:
\begin{xltabular}[H]
\caption{List of published articles selected for the systematic review}
\label{tbl:table2}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Systematic/table.pdf}
\end{xltabular}

But only one page shows the table + this way cause a problem for me since I can't show the citation in the second column.

Comment: @asiddiq: What does "The text in the columns are over each other" mean?